# How to get real image pixel point x,y from PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `pictureBox2` and it is set to `zoom`, I am trying to find out how to to get a real x,y pixel location on the image by `Mouse.Click` on `pictureBox2`.  but I tried 3 possible ideas I knew of: without/with `PointToClient`,`PointToScreen` but I can never get it right.

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    txtpictureHeight.Text =( 
        (OriginalImage.GetImageHeight()*me.Location.Y)/ pictureBox2.Image.Height).ToString();
    txtpictureWidth.Text = ( 
        (OriginalImage.GetImageWidth()* me.Location.X)/ pictureBox2.Image.Width).ToString();
}
```

There must be some factor I need to take care of so I thought to use double result from above and I get closed but there is still 80px off for the height on my test image (1371x2221).  As I use `Zoom` so there are 2 extra spaces on my `pictureBox2`

Comment: You need to calculate the difference between the the size of the picture box and the size of your image.  This will give you the padding you need to apply to your click.

Comment: I don't think `pictureBox2.Image.Height` gives the height of the shown image - just the height of the image object loaded inside, which should be identical to the original image. That object does not change by resizing the control. Use `pictureBox2.ClientRectangle.Height` instead.

Comment: Also, consider using `MouseDown` instead of `Click`, then you got a mouse event to immediately get an `e.X` and `e.Y` which are relative to your control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that with `SizeMode` set to `Zoom`, the `PictureBox` keeps aspect ratio, and centers the image, so on top of calculating the adjusted coordinates, you *also* have to take padding into account.

My advice, don't use the `Click` event; it is meant to detect button clicks, not to actually process interaction of the mouse with an object. Use `MouseDown` instead.

The first thing we need to do is get the width and height of the original image. As I noted in my comment, this is simply the object inside the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`.

Next, we need the dimensions and location of the zoomed image. For that, we can start from the dimensions of the `ClientRectangle` of the `PictureBox`. Divide those by the image width and height and you'll get the horizontal and vertical zoom values. If the `SizeMode` would be set to `StretchImage`, that'd be all we need, but since aspect ratio is conserved, you need the smallest of the two values to have the actual zoom factor.

Once we got that, multiply the original width and height by this zoom factor to get the zoomed width and height, then subtract that from the actual `ClientRectangle` dimensions and divide it by two to get the padding for both dimensions. This can of course be simplified by checking which of the two possible zoom factors is used, and only calculating the padding for the other one, since the dimension of which the zoom factor was used obviously has 0 padding.

Now you got the padding and zoom factor, the rest is simple: subtract the padding values from the mouse coordinates, and then divide both results by the zoom factor.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Default check: left mouse button only
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        ShowCoords(e.X, e.Y);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Allows dragging to also update the coords. Checking the button
    // on a MouseMove is an easy way to detect click dragging.
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        ShowCoords(e.X, e.Y);
}

private void ShowCoords(Int32 mouseX, Int32 mouseY)
{
    Int32 realW = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
    Int32 realH = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
    Int32 currentW = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width;
    Int32 currentH = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height;
    Double zoomW = (currentW / (Double)realW);
    Double zoomH = (currentH / (Double)realH);
    Double zoomActual = Math.Min(zoomW, zoomH);
    Double padX = zoomActual == zoomW ? 0 : (currentW - (zoomActual * realW)) / 2;
    Double padY = zoomActual == zoomH ? 0 : (currentH - (zoomActual * realH)) / 2;

    Int32 realX = (Int32)((mouseX - padX) / zoomActual);
    Int32 realY = (Int32)((mouseY - padY) / zoomActual);
    lblPosXval.Text = realX < 0 || realX > realW ? "-" : realX.ToString();
    lblPosYVal.Text = realY < 0 || realY > realH ? "-" : realY.ToString();
}
```

[image: Example project]

Note, I used sharp pixel zoom here to better show the effect. It's a little trick you can do by subclassing `PictureBox` and overriding its `OnPaint` method, to adjust the `Graphics` object from the `PaintEventArgs` object and set its `InterpolationMode` to `NearestNeighbor` (It's also advised to set `PixelOffsetMode` to `Half`; there's a bug where sharp zoom is shifted half a pixel *unless* you do that). Then you call `base.OnPaint()` with that adjusted event args object.

I also added some more info on it here, but that's all just stuff you can get from the in-between values of the pixel coordinates calculation process anyway.

Comment: Of course, a lot of this can be avoided by sizing the box yourself. I got a project with a pixel editor where I needed this kind of thing too, but I just put the `ImageBox` inside a `Frame` (to automatically get scrollbars), and I sized the `ImageBox` to an exact multiple of the image dimensions based on the value of a `NumericUpDown` control. Exact zoom level set externally. Then you don't need to calculate anything; there is no auto-padding, and the zoom is in the `NumericUpDown`. Just divide the `X` and `Y` from the mouse args by the zoom factor , and you're done.

Comment: @UlinkSecret If you're interested... I uploaded this test project [here](http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/project_stuff/2018/PictureCoords/). The aforementioned pixel editor project is in there too somewhere, in the 2016 folder. It's called "WWFontEditor".